# Cancel Retrofit 2.0 pending network call of specific Activity

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to cancel `retrofit calls` started from an `activity` while I am exiting from that specific `activity`. 
Problem is if I cancel `request` then if I have any `pending request` from other `activity` or `service` that will be cancelled too!

I want to filter the `request` by `activity` and cancel them accordingly.

Comment: I think getting the underlying okhttp object can help you cancel the calls

Comment: can you please elaborate how this can be done ?

Comment: okhttpclient.dispatcher().cancelAll()

Comment: i can cancel but i want to only cancel calls which are started from specific activity not all ongoing calls

Comment: you can invoke call.cancel() on a particular request, for multiple requests I don't think there is a direct way. Maybe use a WeakHashMap or maybe Interceptors might help.

Comment: thanks may be i'm using a singleton to make it easier that's why! i should separate call object